# using Data.Map.map to sum values

Tags: haskell

I want to sum Doubles with the Data.Map.map function.

So i want to have a function like this:

```hs
sumTheDoubles :: Mapping.Map Char [(Char, Double)] -> Mapping.Map Char [(Char, Double)]
```

I want to have a sum all Doubles with the Data.Map.map function:

lets say

```hs
sumTheDoubles (fromList [('i', [('a', 1.0), ('n', 2.0)])])
```

should do: ​1.0 + 2.0 -->

```hs
(fromList [('i', [('a', 3.0), ('n', 3.0)])])
```

Yet my main problem is, that I do not really understand how to access the Doubles with the Data.Map.map function.

Comment: This is an odd signature for a function that _sums_. Surely you should implement it as a simple `-> Double` result, and then replacing that value into all the tuples can be a separate task.

Comment: You can use `Data.Map.map` to replace the value once you've calculated it, but it's not really appropriate for doing the summing.

Comment: @leftaroundabout But I wonder how I can give a double, if I need plenty of them.
Because in the example the size of the map is 1, but can of course be higher than 1.
So i should use a list, and then replace fst element of the List with the first Element of the Map?

Comment: Well, maybe it should be `Mapping.Map Char Double`, if you sum for each element in the `Map` separately (not clear from the question). But not `Mapping.Map Char [(Char, Double)]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradually, I got to this oneliner:

```
sumTheDoubles' f = Mapping.map (\a -> map ((\b -> \(c,d) -> (c,b)) ((sum.map snd) a)) a) f
```

How did I get this result?
I started at the highest level. Then I defined more and more functions as needed. Always I first determined the type of individual function. Finally, I converted the functions to lambda form (from the bottom) and applied them to the top level.

```
module Main where

import qualified Data.Map as Mapping

sumTheDoubles :: Mapping.Map Char [(Char, Double)] -> Mapping.Map Char [(Char, Double)]
sumTheDoubles a = Mapping.map map2 a

-- combine sum and replace
map2 :: [(Char, Double)] -> [(Char, Double)]
map2 a = map (map3 $ map4 a) a

-- replace snd
map3 :: Double -> (Char, Double) -> (Char, Double)
map3 a (b,c) = (b,a)

-- sum Doubles
map4 :: [(Char, Double)] -> Double
map4 a = (sum.map snd) a

main = putStrLn $ show $ sumTheDoubles $ Mapping.fromList [('i', [('a', 1.0), ('n', 2.0)])]
```

Output:

```
fromList [('i',[('a',3.0),('n',3.0)])]
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem to make much sense to construct a `Map Char [(Char, Double)]`: the second item of all the 2-tuples in the list will be the same. It makes more sense to construct a `Map Char Double`, where we thus have summed up the second item of the 2-tuples of the list of values.

We can construct such map with:

```
sumTheDoubles :: Mapping.Map Char [(Char, Double)] -> Mapping.Map Char Double
sumTheDoubles = fmap (sum . map snd)
```

we here make use of [**`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) to apply a function to all values in the `Map`, and for each of these values we first construct a list of second items of the original list, and then use `sum` to sum these together.

If you really want to use a list of elements, you can work with:

```
sumTheDoubles :: Mapping.Map Char [(Char, Double)] -> Mapping.Map Char Double
sumTheDoubles = fmap (\xs -> map (sum (map snd xs) <$) xs)
```